# Email not sending in unity android?

Tags: android, email, unity-game-engine

I have looked many source and question but I am still not clear to how this code of sending email through unity is not working in android build. It works fine in windows build but doesn't work in android. Can someone help me. Here is the code -

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using UnityEngine;
public class EmailUnity
{

public static string SenderEmail;
public static string SenderPassword;
public static string SmtpClient;
public static int SmtpPort;

public static void SendEmail(string to, string subject, string body, bool isHtml, string[] attachmentPaths,
    Action<object, AsyncCompletedEventArgs> callback = null)
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient emailServer = new SmtpClient(SmtpClient, SmtpPort);
        emailServer.EnableSsl = true;
        emailServer.Credentials = (ICredentialsByHost) new NetworkCredential(SenderEmail, SenderPassword);

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(SenderEmail, to);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = body;
        message.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;

        foreach (string path in attachmentPaths)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && File.Exists(path))
            {
                message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(path));
            }
        }
        if (callback == null)
        {
            callback = SampleCallback;
        }
        emailServer.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(callback);
        emailServer.SendAsync(message, "");

        Debug.Log("Email sending");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error: " + ex.Message);
        callback("", new AsyncCompletedEventArgs(ex, true, "Exception occured"));
    }
}

private static void SampleCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled || e.Error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Email sent");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *doen't work in android*? Please describe it.

Comment: Please provide the code where you call the method `SendEmail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the things to try if `SmtpClient` is not working on Android.

Go to *File* --> *Build Settings...* --> Select *Android*. Now, click on *Player Settings*.

**1**.On the *Internet Access*, change it from *Auto* to *Require*.

**2**.Make sure that API Compatible Level is set to *.NET 2.0* not *.NET 2.0 Subset*.

**3**.Make sure that *Stripping Level* is set to *Disabled*.

**4**.Go to *Player settings* --> *Android* and change *Internet Access* from *Auto* to *Require*

Comment: Thanks a lot. forgot to change .NET Subset to .NET. The email is working but now the attachment(image) is not attaching with the mail.

Comment: The attachment is really a whole different problem. You should create a new question about attachment not working. Please show us what the path of the Attachment looks like and how you construct that path.

Comment: Thanks for replying I will do that